# Unclear about the definition of "closed"?

Tags: general-topology

A number of resources online cite the definition of "closed" as a set containing all its limit points. But this statements seems to be always true to me.

A limit point is one having at least one point of the set (other than that point itself) in every neighborhood. So limit points are like a true/false thing for each and every point in the set. So won't a set always contain its limit points?

What is wrong in my argument?

Comment: Think about that : $0$ is a limit point of $(0,1]$ (for the usual topology)

Comment: But 0 isn't contained in that set right?

Comment: @Kalpesh: Right – and that’s exactly the point: $0$ is not contained in that set, but it *is* a limit point of that set, because every nbhd of $0$ contains points of $(0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, so this is an exemple of a set that doesn't contain all its limits points

Comment: And not every point of a set is a limit point: consider the set $\{0\} \cup [1,2]$; there is a neighborhood of $0$ that is disjoint from $[0,1]$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $x$ is a limit point of $X$ if for every open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ we have $U-\{x\}\cap X\neq \emptyset$. Thus, $\{1/n; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point and $0\notin \{1/n; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. On the other hand, $\{0\}\cup \{1/n; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is closed.